# Sort by named capture group within regular expression in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, sorting, capture-group

I have a regular expression defined as follows:

```
$regexpo = "^Amma\s(?'version'(\d+\.){3}\d)\.zip$"
```

The above expression has label attached with a group - (\d+.){3}\d)

And I am using it as follows:

```
$Library =  $wholeContent | 
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match $regexpo } | 
    Sort-Object Name -Descending
```

But I want to sort it by the labelled group within the defined regular expression instead, which represents a version number.

Comment: you need to recalc the calculated property in the S-O segment of your pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) with a calculated property (a script block (`{ ... }`) that is evaluated for each input object, reflected in `$_`) as follows:

```bsh
# Sample input
$wholeContent = 
  [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'Amma 10.0.0.1.zip'; Type = '...' },
  [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'Not a match' ; Type = '...' },
  [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'Amma 1.0.0.2.zip' ; Type = '...' },
  [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'Amma 2.1.2.3.zip' ; Type = '...' }

# Define the regex that matches the full name
# and captures the embedded version number in named capture group 'version'.
# Better to use '...' (single quotes) to define regexes, to prevent
# confusion with string expansion inside "..."
# Note the alternate syntax `<version>` instead of `'version'`.
$regex = '^Amma\s(?<version>(\d+\.){3}\d+)\.zip$'

# Filter by the line of interest, then sort by the extracted version number.
# Automatic variable $Matches is a hashtable that contains the results of
# the regex match, with entry 'version' containing the capture group's value. 
# Casting to [version] ensures that version-appropriate sorting is used.
$wholeContent |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match $regex } | 
    Sort-Object { [version] ($_.Name -replace $regex, '${version}') }
```

Note that matching *twice* is required here<sup>[1]</sup>: once to filter in the lines of interest, and again to extract the embedded version text, via the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

<sup>Note: Use of `-replace` with the original regex here is possible, because the regex at hand is designed to match the *whole* input string, which allows replacing the whole string with just the named capture group's value (`${version}`) to yield only the latter; the more verbose alternative is to use another `-match` operation to obtain the capture-group value via `$Matches`:

`$null = $_.Name -match $regex; $Matches['version']`</sup>

The above yields the following, showing that only the lines of interest were extracted, properly sorted by version number:

```
Name              Type
----              ----
Amma 1.0.0.2.zip  ...
Amma 2.1.2.3.zip  ...
Amma 10.0.0.1.zip ...
```

---

<sup>[1] While the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), populated by a `-match` operation, *is* available in script blocks in subsequent pipeline segments in principle, allowing access to the results of the matching operation, it cannot be utilized here, because `Sort-Object` is of necessity an *aggregating* cmdlet; that is, it must *collect all input first* in order to perform sorting, at which point using `$Matches` in the calculated property only contains the *last* input object's matches.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of sorting by a regex match, by the last character.

```
echo a3 b2 c1 | sort { $_ -match "(?'last'.$)"; $matches.last }                                               

c1
b2
a3
```